# getting error on installing package pyldap-2.4.45 on pypy3 environment

Tags: django, pypy, pyldap

cc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/LDAPObject.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/ldapcontrol.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/common.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/constants.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/errors.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/functions.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/schema.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/ldapmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/message.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/version.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/options.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/Modules/berval.o -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -R/usr/lib -R/usr/lib64 -R/usr/local/lib -R/usr/local/lib64 -lldap_r -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_ldap.pypy3-510-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’ 
    cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’ 
    cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’ 
    cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-R’ 
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/home/synerg-root/SAFE_V2/my-safe-pypy-env/bin/pypy3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-iqwhlb2g-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-z13bd00v-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/synerg-root/SAFE_V2/my-safe-pypy-env/include/site/python3.5/pyldap" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-iqwhlb2g-build/

Comment: did u installed the development libraries of pyldap like libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev

Comment: I had run this command: sudo apt-get install python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev

Comment: this pypy3 is in virtualenv